# Native Query returns list with java.lang.Object instead of custom object type in JPA application

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, type-conversion

I have the following tables in my MySQL database:

```
Student
id | firstName | lastName | ...

Course
id | name | cp | ...
-

CourseResult (course_id and student_id are created by JPA)
id | course_id | student_id | grade | ...
-
```

I am trying to work with all `Students` who are in a `Course` defined by a given `course_id`. For that I've created a method in my controller:

```
public String showCourseResultList(Course course) {
    this.course = course;
    studentsInCourse = new ArrayList<Student>();
    studentsInCourse = em
            .createNativeQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE id IN (SELECT student_id FROM CourseResult WHERE course_id = ?)")
            .setParameter(1, course.getId()).getResultList();
    System.out.println(studentsInCourse);
    return "courseResultList?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

So in the NativeQuery I am detecting all `student_ids` for a given `course_id`. Then I use the `student_ids` to select all `Students` from the `Student` table.
In other words I want to collect all `Students` in an `ArrayList<Student>`, who are in the given `Course`.

The problem is, that after doing that, the `ArrayList<T>` contains elements from the type `java.lang.Object` instead of my custom type `Student`.
The `System.out.println(studentsInCourse);` returns `[[Ljava.lang.Object;@3adaf419, [Ljava.lang.Object;@7ccfb37e]`.

How can I collect all the `Students` from type `Student` in my `ArrayList<T>` instead of `ArrayList<java.lang.Object>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give the classname you expect as the second argument of your createNativeQuery call:

```
studentsInCourse = em
            .createNativeQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE id IN (SELECT student_id FROM CourseResult WHERE course_id = ?)", Student.class)
            .setParameter(1, course.getId()).getResultList();
```